# Encrypt word X to /etc/shadow encryption

Tags: password, encryption, openssl

I've changed my password to X and the shadow file has changed to:

```
ahmad:$1$oYINSKjP$eCkCtJV/2dXerAD57WQPj/:15425:0:99999:7:::
```

I see the encrypted `X` as `$1$oYINSKjP$eCkCtJV/2dXerAD57WQPj/`. How can I retrieve the encrypted `X` without changing the password? openssl or any other command to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your password isn't encrypted. It is *hashed*.

A salted MD5 hash has been generated and written to `/etc/shadow`. You cannot retrieve original value.

The original value `X` has been hashed in this format: `$id$salt$encrypted - id == 1` stands for MD5 (see `NOTES` on manpage of `crypt(3)`)

Comment: Thanks. Now how can I hash `X` into `$id$salt$encrypted` on the command line?

Comment: openssl passwd -1 -salt salt password